# A bit more explanation on how to use jemalloc statistics

Tags: memory-management, memory-leaks, jemalloc

Besides being an apparently good memory allocation library `jemalloc` also offers built-in allocation statistics. However this requires some understanding on `jemalloc`'s internal data structures. So when I call `malloc_stats_print(NULL, NULL, NULL)`, I get quite some output similar to what the jemalloc people show on [their github wiki page](https://github.com/jemalloc/jemalloc/wiki/Use-Case%3A-Basic-Allocator-Statistics).

So my own use case for using these statistics is to see which type of allocations seems to be net growing over time in a problematic way. Say that I have some type of object of size ***S*** for which I think this growth is happening. How can I check that using periodic calls to `malloc_stats_print`?

Furthermore what is the difference between `nmalloc` and `nrequests` and which other metrics of the full output of this call should I care about in search for unaccounted memory growth.